# Android - crashes when calling objects

Tags: java, android, function, methods

I have a working code now with my thesis but I decided to clean it up using functions/methods/objects (not really sure what to call them) but after organizing them, my app crashes everytime i start it. I dont really know what the problem is.

Main Screen shows Start and Exit Button. When I press START, the app says "Unfortunately thesis has stopped".

My code goes like this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.items, menu);
    View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    final EditText txtSearch = ( EditText ) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_search);
    txtSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            String curtextArray = txtSearch.getText().toString();
            char[] curletters = curtextArray.toCharArray();
            char[] curenhancedLetters = curtextArray.toCharArray();

//probably, problem here on Stemming stem
            Stemming stem = new Stemming(curtextArray, curletters, curenhancedLetters);
            AsyncTaskRunner newTask = new AsyncTaskRunner(enhancedStem);

// and probably, problem is here on the stem.<x process>;
            stem.removeApostrophe();
            stem.vowelMarking();
            stem.shortSyllable();
            if (continueStem == 1){
                stem.region1();
                stem.region2();
                stem.shortWord();
                stem.step0();
                stem.step1a();
                stem.step1b();
                newTask.execute();
            }
            return false;
        };
    });     
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

}

Here's my Stemming Class

```
public class Stemming {
    String textArray;
    char[] letters;
    char[] enhancedLetters;


    public Stemming (String curtextArray, char[] curletters, char[] curenhancedLetters){
        this.textArray = curtextArray;
        this.letters = curletters;
        this.enhancedLetters = curenhancedLetters;
    }

    public Stemming(){

    }

     public void removeApostrophe(){
       ...processes here
     }
     public void vowelMarking(){
       ...processes here
     }
     public void shortSyllable(){
       ...processes here
     }

    public void region1(){
       ...processes here
     }
     public void region2(){
       ...processes here
     }
     public void shortWord(){
       ...processes here
     }
     public void step0(){
       ...processes here
     }
     public void step1a(){
       ...processes here
     }
     public void step1b(){
       ...processes here
     }
}
```

}

I have a theory on why it crashes. Is this method possible? (pseudocode):

```
public class Stemming {
String result;
String sample = "A A A A A";

public void changeAtoB{

    //do process to convert all As to Bs making String sample = "B B B B B"
    result = sample;
}

   public void changeBtoC{
   //do process to convert all Bs to Cs making String result = "C C C C C"
   result = result;
}

   ... so on {
   }
}
```

What I did was process the string in a straight manner without doing any variable declarations (my variables are declared globally) or initializations. and I also did not put any return statements.

My code used to work when It was still without those functions/methods/objects.

Sorry about my long post. Don't know how to explain it better. I hope you help me. Thank you in Advance!

LOGCAT:

```
>E/AndroidRuntime(11007): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.atienzaerni.thesis/com.atienzaerni.thesis.secondactivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at com.atienzaerni.thesis.secondactivity.<init>(secondactivity.java:54)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
E/AndroidRuntime(11007): ... 11 more
I/Process(11007): Sending signal. PID: 11007 SIG: 9
```

(I'm using my phone by the way. Not an emulator. If this makes a difference)

Comment: Please provide a stacktrace of the crash.

Comment: it could be anything, post the logcat

Comment: just use copy paste in logcat  its a greencolorDroid

Comment: where is line 54 in secondactivity.java

Comment: Line 54 is just a blank line. nothing on it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting a NullPointerException because v is null at this line:

```
    final EditText txtSearch = ( EditText ) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_search);
```

This is probably caused by null being returned from the menu items action view here:

```
    View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
```

You should either set the action view in code and not call getActionView or make sure you have a proper action view set in the menu XML. Without seeing your menu XML it's hard to tell if the problem lies in the XML.

Comment: Actually, I don't even see the screen where that editText is. I have a main screen that shows "Start" and "Exit". When I click Start, what happens is "unfortunately thesis has stopped" immediately. But before doing the function stuff, it works flawlessly.

Comment: The function onCreateOptionsMenu is called right as an activity is being created if it is in the action bar. Is the onCreateOptionsMenu function you posted above in the activity you are trying to launch? If it is it will cause a crash before you actually see the new activity displayed.

Comment: yes, the edittext is in the action bar. but the crash happens when i transformed my code into like that. Using functions to make it look 'cleaner'. Before, all my codes are packed inside the oncreate options menu.

Comment: What line of code is at com.atienzaerni.thesis.secondactivity line 54?